# How to client-side sort inertia data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a component that receive data. In my controller I have:

```
route::get('/', function() { return inertia('foo', ['data' => Model::all()]) });
```

On my Vue component:

```
<template>
   <ul> 
      <li v-for="item in data">{{item.name}}</li>
   </ul>
</template>
<script setup>
defineProps({ data: Object })
</script>
```

My goal is to be able to display the data either by `name` or `score` depending on the value of a checkbox. I don't think it is a good idea to send the request on the server-side, so I would like to do it on the component.

Unfortunately, props are read only, and it is not possible to do something like this:

```
 <li v-for="Object(data).sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)">
```

Any other suggestion?

The type of my `props.data` is:

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}, 10: {…}, 11: {…}, 12: {…}, 13: {…}, 14: {…}, 15: {…}, 16: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
0: {id: 1, user: null, name: 'foobar', score: 0, …}
1: {id: 2, user: null, name: 'baz', score: 10, …}
```

And `Object(props.data)` doesn't have a `sort` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
const props = defineProps({ data: Object });
const sortByScore = ref(true);
const sortBy = computed(() => (sortByScore.value ? "score" : "name"));
const sortedData = computed(() =>
  Object.values(props.data).sort((a, b) => b[sortBy.value] - a[sortBy.value])
);
</script>
```

And link `sortByScore` to the checkbox.

---

I don't like having to deal with `.value` in my controllers, so I'd write it as:

```
import { reactive, computed, toRefs } from "vue";
const props = defineProps({ data: Object });
const state = reactive({
  sortByScore: true,
  sortBy: computed(() => (state.sortByScore ? "score" : "name")),
  sortedData: computed(() =>
    Object.values(props.data).sort((a, b) => b[state.sortBy] - a[state.sortBy])
  ),
});


// expose state, so you don't have to use `state.sortedData` in `<template>`
const { sortByScore, sortBy, sortedData } = toRefs(state);
```

I find `reactive()` syntax cleaner, especially in large controllers.
Another advantage of this syntax is you can type the state using only one interface.

Another thing I've seen others do is to name `state` as `S` and no longer unwrap it for `<template>`. Just use it as `S.sortByScore`, `S.sortedData`, etc.
This way you don't have to re-type all the keys you want exposed. Sometimes I wish there was an equivalent for `return {...toRefs(state)}` in `<script setup>`.

---

Note: the above transforms your data from Object to Array. It's the only way to guarantee the order of elements. Object props can't be reliably sorted in JavaScript.

Comment: I have `const props = defineProps({ data: Object })` but the `props.data.sort` throw me an exception `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: props.data.sort is not a function`.

Comment: I tried the same with `Object(props.data).sort` :(

Comment: What is the shape of your `data` variable? @nowox

Comment: @kissu I have updated my question with an answer to your question

Comment: @novox, you need to use `Object.values(props.data)`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example)

```html
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({ data: Object })

const sortedData = computed(() => Object(props.data.value).sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score))
</script>
```

Also, in your `v-for` don't forget [the `:key`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key) with a UUID preferably!

Comment: Side question, how do you know to use `import {computed} from 'vue'`? On the documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html), they don't give the composition api example. I am struggling with this new composition API.

Comment: I get `Object(props.data).sort is not a function`.

Comment: @nowox only [`defineProps` and `defineEmits`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) are baked-in into the compiler, for the rest you need to import hem. Overall, you can use ESlint and get all the warnings for a faster debugging experience. For the last error, it's because you don't have any `props` variable. Give a try to `const props = defineProps({ data: Object })`. Also, you can totally still use Options API if you prefer that over Composition API.